# My app stops working in the AVD

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I'm very new.
I don't have any error warning, but when I test, it unfortunately stops working.
I've changed the AVD ram value, but still not work.
I tried to export it to my phone, but it fails to install.

my activity file

```
package com.abdo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private static String logtag = "TwoButtonApp";//for use as the tag when logging 

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);        
     buttonStart.setOnClickListener(startListener); // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above

     Button buttonStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);        
     buttonStop.setOnClickListener(stopListener); // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
    }

    //Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
    private OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Log.d(logtag,"onClick() called - start button");   
          Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ManuActivity.class);
          startActivity(a);

          Log.d(logtag,"onClick() ended - start button");
        }
    };

    // Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
    private OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Log.d(logtag,"onClick() called - stop button"); 
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The Stop button was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Log.d(logtag,"onClick() ended - stop button");
        } 
    };


    @Override
 protected void onStart() {//activity is started and visible to the user
  Log.d(logtag,"onStart() called");
  super.onStart();  
 }
 @Override
 protected void onResume() {//activity was resumed and is visible again
  Log.d(logtag,"onResume() called");
  super.onResume();

 }
 @Override
 protected void onPause() { //device goes to sleep or another activity appears
  Log.d(logtag,"onPause() called");//another activity is currently running (or user has pressed Home)
  super.onPause();

 }
 @Override
 protected void onStop() { //the activity is not visible anymore
  Log.d(logtag,"onStop() called");
  super.onStop();

 }
 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {//android has killed this activity
   Log.d(logtag,"onDestroy() called");
   super.onDestroy();
 }
}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abdo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.abdo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.abdo.ManuActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_manu" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: check your `logcat` for any exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Firstly set the `android:debuggable` to true in your manifest file.
- Secondly, turn on `install apk from unknown sources` in your android device's settings and also turn on `allow to debug through usb` setting in `developer settings` or kinda that (don't know how this calls on english, I have russian interface).
- Then run your code in debug mode, pressing `debug` button in your IDE.

And also try to write your code `after` the `super` function call.

```
 @Override
 protected void onStart() {//activity is started and visible to the user
  super.onStart();  
  Log.d(logtag,"onStart() called");
 }
```